# No sound on laptop speakers in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, dell, 18.04, lts

New to Ubuntu (apart from trying it for a short time years ago) and cannot get the sound to work. I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 in a dual-boot setup (had Windows 7 for years on the computer with no sound issues) on a Dell Inspiron N5110.

I have tried to resolve this in numerous ways:

-> Checked that the sound is not muted

-> Checked that the OS recognizes the sound device (shows as "Speakers - Built -in Audio" in sound settings, and as "HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH" in System Profiler and Benchmark)

-> Followed instructions (on https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) to reinstall Alsa and Pulse audio, and edit the speech-dispatcher file

-> Tested sound on "Test Speakers" in sound settings, and on Youtube and Twitter videos on both Firefox and Chromium

-> In Windows (where sound comes through the laptop speakers with no issues), the audio drivers are "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC, driver version: 6.10.0.6324, and Intel(R) Display Audio, driver version: 6.14.0.3074.

I've tested the sound with external speakers and headphones and they seem to work, so suspect this could be a driver issue but not certain - and don't know how to resolve this if this is the case especially since, as mentioned, sound settings and System Profiler and Benchmark seem to recognize the hardware.

None of the above methods I've tried have worked. I'm hoping to use Ubuntu instead of Windows as much as possible to try to learn more about Linux, so using Ubuntu for regular use (including media) should hopefully help - so if anyone knows how to resolve this it'd be appreciated (suppose this issue in itself might be good for learining though).

Comment: please post the output of this command :

pacmd list-sinks

Comment: *I've tested the sound with external speakers and headphones and they seem to work...* What does that mean? I thought you said you had no sound.

Comment: @ Paul - It means that the sound seems to work with headphones and external speakers. I.e via the 3.5mm audio output port. The issue I'm experiencing is that there is no sound on the laptop speakers . I.e the internal speakers located inside the laptop and directly attached to the motherboard.

Comment: Thanks cmak. Used the pacmd list-sinks command, tried with pastebinit so hopefully this link works;
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NYPzdJ6mXS/

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your audio if your external speakers and headphones work fine. It can't be a driver issue as neither would work. I don't use pulse-audio but I'd be inclined to think the issue with internal speakers probably lies there. You could also run `alsamixer` and see if you recognise your laptop speakers output  in there and if they've been muted.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried your suggestion but I don't think that's the cause as "HDA Intel PCH" is there on the top left of the screen as the "Card" in alsamixer, and I don't think it's been muted as "Master" has numbers under its column relating to the sound it should play at (0-100).
I'll maybe try booting into Windows and see if the card has a different name there in case Ubuntu has somehow confused it with another card? As mentioned, I'm pretty much new to all of this so I may not be getting this right.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
Had a loose cable inside of the case that connected to speakers - probably from an unrelated repair I did just before installing Ubuntu.

Sound was working in Windows before said repair, then carried out this repair (forgot to reconnect a cable), then installed Ubuntu immediately afterwards. This made it appear (falsely) as though the issue was somehow related to the newly-installed OS when it was actually hardware-based. Rookie mistake. Thanks to those who tried helping.